# Java equivalent to scala's concat when joining columns in apache spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

In scala I can join multiple columns in a dataframe to a new column, e.g.

```
var dataWithNewColumns = rawData.withColumn("day_and_time", concat(rawData("day"),lit("_"),rawData("time")))
```

I'd like to do the same in java but I cannot find any equivalent to the *concat* function. Can you help me out? Any other option to achive a combination of both columns is welcome, as well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to import `functions` class (or rather, `static` methods of it) in your class in order to achieve it, e.g.:

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;
```

Once you have imported it, this is how the code will look like:

```
Dataset<Row> data = //get data
data.withColumn("new_Column", concat(data.col("col1"), lit("_"), data.col("col2")));
```

Comment: Thanks Darshan, that is exactly what I was looking for.